# Spark looks "zombie" on EMR cluster

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

We are running a simple spark application that executes multiple count() functions on each column for a given dataframe.
After few jobs the application seems "stuck", it looks like it still running (there are active tasks on executors), but nothing actually happens (for 3 hours until I kill it).
In Ganglia we see that all of the nodes are on <5% cpu usage.
When we execute this application again (without changing anything) it finishes after 10 minutes.

More details:

1. We run spark on EMR cluster, 20 nodes.
2. Dataframe contains ~20M rows.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any SPOT instances in your cluster? If so, which ratio of Spot to on-demand instances? Do you see any failures of executors in Spark logs/UI?

Comment: Yes,we have we have 19 nodes that are spots and 1 node on-demand. we didn't see errors on the executors.

Comment: Try running the job on a cluster of only on-demand instances. I frequently see Spark clusters being stuck because of SPOT instance issues